# Why I am getting error while loading pos tagger?

Tags: servlets, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to write code for lemma, pos, ner, tokenize but facing many issues, one of the issues is this error. How can I solve this error?
I am bound to use servlet for the main work and I have written pipeline in java class.
Please help.. Thanks in advance.

**Note- I am using Stanford corenlp 3.9.2**

Pipeline.java

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;

import java.util.Properties;

public class Pipeline {

    private static Properties properties;
    private static String propertiesName = "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, sentiment";
    private static StanfordCoreNLP stanfordCoreNLP;

    private Pipeline() { }

    static {
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("annotators", propertiesName);
    }

    public static StanfordCoreNLP getPipeline() {
        if(stanfordCoreNLP == null) {
            stanfordCoreNLP = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties);
        }
        return stanfordCoreNLP;
    }
}
```

Preprocessing_UserContent.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.List;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.CoreDocument;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet("/Preprocessing_UserContent")
public class Preprocessing_UserContent extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Preprocessing_UserContent</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            
            StanfordCoreNLP stanfordCoreNLP = Pipeline.getPipeline();

            String text = request.getParameter("textblock");
            out.println("text");

            CoreDocument coreDocument = new CoreDocument(text);

            stanfordCoreNLP.annotate(coreDocument);

            List<CoreLabel> coreLabelList = coreDocument.tokens();

            for(CoreLabel coreLabel : coreLabelList) {

                String lemma = coreLabel.lemma();

                out.println(coreLabel.originalText() + " = "+ lemma);

            }

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);  
    }
}
```

Any solution for this error?

```
04-Oct-2020 21:10:31.630 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-207] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Preprocessing_UserContent] in context with path [/MultiLabelDataClassification] threw exception
        edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:799)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:320)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:273)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:85)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:73)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.posTagger(AnnotatorImplementations.java:53)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$3(StanfordCoreNLP.java:521)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$null$30(StanfordCoreNLP.java:602)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:126)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:149)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:251)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:192)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:188)
            at Pipeline.getPipeline(Pipeline.java:32)
            at Preprocessing_UserContent.processRequest(Preprocessing_UserContent.java:28)
            at Preprocessing_UserContent.doPost(Preprocessing_UserContent.java:62)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as class path, filename or URL
            at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:480)
            at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:796)
            ... 40 more
```

Comment: Are you managing your depedency using Maven ? Can you please share which all depedencies you have included in your project ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sariq Shaikh, I have already got the solution. The problem was in the version of stanford corenlp I was using.